# Creating rule to update node title

Tags: nodes, rules, users

When a visitor registers on my site, I have a set of rules that create several nodes. One of those nodes is a photo gallery.

The rule for the creation of the gallery title, includes the following: *[account:name]'s Photo Gallery* and that works fine.

But if the user changes his name later on, the name on the photo gallery is not updated.

I have been struggling with the creation of a rule to do just that but I haven't found the option or configuration that allows me to update the node title.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with Rules.

1. Add a new Reaction Rule (e.g: Update user gallery title)
2. Event: "After updating an existing user account"
3. Action: "Fetch entity by property":

   - type = node
   - title = [account:name]'s Photo Gallery
4. Loop over 'list item' and add action
5. Action: "Set data value": Set list_item item title
6. Save list_item.

Update: rule export:

```
{ "rules_update_gallery_title" : {
    "LABEL" : "Update user gallery title",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "user_update" ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "property" : "title",
            "value" : "[account-unchanged:name]\u0027s gallery"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "entity-fetched" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "data_set" : {
                "data" : [ "list-item:title" ],
                "value" : "[account:name]\u0027s gallery"
              }
            },
            { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "list-item" ], "immediate" : 1 } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks logical at first sight but the data selectors do not allow the "title=[account:name]'s Photo Gallery" or "Set data value": Update entity_fetched item title." That's for Drupal version 7. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @user14666 actually it does work, needed to save rule to get value option for setting title. Also need to loop over entity_fetched as list_item as multiple values can be returned. Note, you can use account-unchanged for original account prior to update. Rules export added.

Comment: Copy and paste of the above generate the following error message: ntegrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message: Data selector <em class="placeholder">list-item:title</em> for parameter <em class="placeholder">data</em> is invalid..

Comment: Do I need an additional plugin for this?

Comment: Hmm, works for me, perhaps you need the 'entity api' module http://drupal.org/project/entity make sure rules is up to date also. Else try recreating the rule via the UI.

Comment: I have Entity. Will check for the latest Rules update. And yes, will try to recreate the same export using Rules UI. :)

Comment: Works great! The problem was I was entering \u0027 instead of the simple ' (apostrophe.)  Thanks a million. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Yes \u0027 is the escaped version for export, it translates to apostrophe ' Cheers